# TFS WIQL ever contains tag Syntax?

Tags: tfs, wiql

Trying to leverage the WIQL Editor feature:
'ever contains tag'

Searching Syntax, Trial and Error

```
Select 
[System.Id], 
[System.Title], 
[System.State],
[System.Tags]
From WorkItems 
Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Change Request' 
AND [State] <> 'Closed' 
AND [State] <> 'Cancelled' 
AND EVER [Tags] CONTAINS 'My Tag'
order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, 
[System.CreatedDate] desc
```

Expect it to return all work items that ever had a specific tag.

Comment: Hi PatrickLu - It was helpful, however I did not implement using the Rest or Client API.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not able to do this through work item query at present.

Even though TFS supports a “Was Ever” operator for work item queries. But this operator is not applicable to all fields.  As you can see, unlike assign to filed, the tag field only have **Contians** and **Does Not Contain** two operators.

[image]

So according to your Syntax `AND EVER [Tags] CONTAINS 'My Tag'`. This will not  return all work items that ever had a specific tag.

For your requirement, you need to use Rest API or Client API to fetch the history of a work item and filter the tag value you have ever added in the record of all history info. It's a little bit complicated.